# optimize and speed up php website

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a service wrote on php. It takes request from the client in the form of URL, inserts it into `Mysql DB` and give response as `successfull` or `failure` to the client. The URL is like:

```
mysite.com/index.php?user=1234&&tokenid="wdsavdcsvc"
```

The problem is `tokenid` is generated by another external executable which takes almost 3 sec to complete, it makes my application(request processing and response basically) slow.

I am running the executable using `$tokenid = shell_exec application arguments`

The worst part is I can't do any change in executable.

I thought I should run the executable as a background process. But I am not sure if it is a right choice.

Is there any way to tune up the app, such that it takes 1000 of request within a second.

**EDIT:**

I don't need to return token at all to the user, I can generate the token and insert it later. It is totally for our purpose.

Comment: Hard to think how something that takes 3 seconds which you can't change can be made to take less than 3 seconds by changing something else.

Comment: bad SO question un-answerable in code or anything else.

Comment: @Dagon This is about the design. How should I change it, not the code.

Comment: @pvg I already gave the hint, *If it is right idea to run the executable in background and proceed to next request*.

Comment: All you need to do is write something in PHP that creates your token and runs in milli seconds. What are the rules for your `token` creation? It does not look like a very complicated string!

Comment: Are you sending the token back to the client? It's really not very clear from your question and the other comments.

Comment: And what is the token used for? it sounds like it's not a timed authentication token, it's just an opaque token. why not just generate a uuid or guid in php?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

OP has clarified that they don't need to return the token ID immediately, and what they really want is an efficient queuing system to process token IDs as background tasks.

The solution here is to create a database table called something like "pending_token_generation" that has the user's information in, perhaps as a foreign key into a "users" table.

Then you should set up a Cron job that runs once a minute (depending on your needs) to pull out one or more rows from that table and generate the token using your executable. As the token is generated, delete the row from "pending_token_generation" and insert the token wherever it is needed – perhaps in the "users" table?

This ought to be wrapped in a transaction to avoid problems.

**Old answer**

If your script relies on that executable, and that executable always takes three seconds to complete, there isn't a lot you can do. If you are happy doing a fair amount of work, then the solution is to have your script respond immediately with a ticket number that the client can then use to re-query your server after five seconds.

If you want to go down that route, here's how it would look:

1) User asks for a token ID.

2) Your server says, "I hear you; here's a ticket number, ask me again in 5 seconds."

3) The server then kicks off the token generation executable, and stores its result in a temporary table next to the ticket number.

4) The client receives and stores the ticket number, then in 5 seconds sends it back to the server: "I asked for a token ID; here's my ticket number."

5) The server looks up the ticket number in your table, finds the token ID next to it, and returns it to the client.

Comment: I am not returning tokenid to user, It is for our reference . I am thinking if this is right to run that executable in background and go to next request.

Comment: Ah! In that case, absolutely, yes: just move on and run that code in the background. BE CAREFUL THOUGH: You don't want to overload your server. You should use a queueing system so that a background task can pick off one job at a time.

Comment: I understand; see my updated answer. It's easier than you think.

Answer (score 1):

The task you're executing that takes 3 seconds has be synchronously I assume, a token is most of the time related to authentication.

As long as you can't change the 3 second task there is no way to speed it up...
The 3rd party is the problem, not a problem with with php/mysql/apache.

If you want a better overview of what your php code is doing during those 3 seconds, install xdebug php extension, it's used for profiling.

You can read the cachegrind files with WinCacheGrind(widows) or kcachegrind(linux).

Don't have any experience with installer xdebug on windows, but on linux is just a yum/apt-get install php-xdebug and configure it.

Further information can be found on [the xdebug website](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) or on the [wincachegrind website](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/)

---

Edit

I saw you updated your post with how you get the token, tbh a shell_exec is a bad idea, will never scale or be reliable enough.
If I were you I'd take a better look at why you need the token, do it yourself(if it's something like auth) or use a different solution if it's not authentication.

If you want more help you'll have to provide us with more info on why and what the shell_exec does, because the problem is not related to the web request.

Answer (score 0):

Performance tuning is all about finding the slowest parts of your system, and fixing those parts.

It sounds like you've already identified the slow part of your system -- the external executable that generates the token. That's the slow part, so that's what you need to fix.

Whether you can do that or not, or how to go about doing it, is impossible for me help with, as you haven't given any clues about it in the question. But if it's going to take 3 seconds, then there's nothing you can do to your PHP code to speed it up, other than swapping out the slow component for something quicker.